# adding elements to json string(array) FLUTTER

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a JSON string, inside of it I have an array, I want to add data to it as I tried to do it below:

```
  String myJSON = '{"listOfSubtasks":["dasd","dadd","dadsd"]}';

  arrayToStringAndBack(addElement) async {
    var json = jsonDecode(myJSON);
    var getArray = json['listOfSubtasks'];  //returns [dasd,dadd,dadsd]
    setState(() {
      getArray.add(addElement);
    });
    // as I want to push it to a db I convert [dasd,dadd,dadsd] to a String ["dasd","dadd","dadsd"]
    String arrayToString = jsonEncode(getArray);
    print(arrayToString);
  }
  ...
  textfieldform
   - onSaved: (val) {
      subtasks = val;
      arrayToStringAndBack(val);
     },
  ...
```

---

When I type smth and click on a submit button an element is added to the end of an array but once I try to do it one more time, to add an element, the last element that was added changes to one I created.
I want to add as many elements as I want, not just a single one

Solved

```
  var arrayOfSubTasks = [];

  arrayToStringAndBack(addElement, arr) async {
    var json = jsonDecode(myJSON);
    var getArray = json['listOfSubtasks'];
    setState(() {
      getArray.add(arr);
    });
    String arrayToString = jsonEncode(getArray);
    print(arrayToString);
  }
  ...
  onSaved: (val) {
    subtasks = val;
    setState(() {
      arrayOfSubTasks.add(val);
    });
    arrayToStringAndBack(val, arrayOfSubTasks);
  },
```

Comment: This seems to be a local List only. Can you use a class member instead?

Comment: @JulienLachal I don't think that I have to create a class for it, I just need a json string with an array that can be modified.

Comment: I guess it's because you start from the myJSON everytime and never replace it with the altered version. So the result will always be the start value in myJSON + the one element you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat your list of subtasks as a List to be able to add String with `List.add()`. Then encode the List to a json with `jsonEncode()`